# Matlab strsplit inputs

Tags: matlab

I am currently using 'strsplit' function in Matlab as:

```
char(strsplit(cell2str({'ASD13456D34567'}),'ASD')')
```

The output of this is:

```
ans =

13456
34567
```

Instead, I want to have output as:

```
13456D34567
```

How do I achieve this ?

I have a cell array of strings. Here I just used one element of the array for illustration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to split strings:

```
regexp({'ASD13456D34567','test'},'ASD','split') %// split according to 'ASD'
```

Or if you just want to remove `'ASD'`, without splitting:

```
regexprep({'ASD13456D34567','test'},'ASD','') %// replace 'ASD' by empty string
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like this:

```
char(strsplit('ASD13456D34567','ASD'))
```

Comment: 2010. My output is: 13456 and 34567

Comment: Mine is 2013. Could you provide another example, please?

Comment: My Matlab (R2009b) says: "Undefined function or method 'strsplit' for input arguments of type 'char'."